# php format a number so that it has leading zero

Tags: php

I want to format my array vars to that numbers under ten have leading zeros, so:

```
$myArray=array(1,2,3,10,11,100);
```

So that it is:

```
$myArray=array(01,02,03,10,11,100);
```

Is there an easy function for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't do this. Add the leading zero at output time instead

Comment: Okay, one way I've thought of is `if(strlen($var)==1)$var="0".$var;` but is there a better way?

Comment: String is fine - it's actually for time "01:59:59", so I'll be strtotime anyway.

Comment: If you're ultimately passing the values through `strtotime()`, why add the zero beforehand?

Comment: Why use `strtotime` if you have `DateTime::createFromFormat`.

Answer (score 5):

In php, a leading zero means the number is a octal number.

You should just format it at the output time like:

```
$myArray=array(1,2,3,10,11,100);
foreach ($myArray as $var) {
  echo sprintf("%02d\n", $var);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This allows you to pad all values to a variable length.

Keep in mind a leading zero is not a valid integer representation. For portability reasons, If you want to store the values, the values should be converted to strings.

```
$myArray = array(1,2,3,10,11,100);
$pad_length = 2;

foreach ($myArray as &$item)
{
    $item = str_pad($item, $pad_length, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

print_r($myArray);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(   
    [0] => 01
    [1] => 02
    [2] => 03
    [3] => 10
    [4] => 11
    [5] => 100
)
```

Answer (score 4):

It's muche better to add the 0 when you print it otherwise you transform them to string:

```
$myArray=array(1,2,3,10,11,100);

foreach ($myArray as $number){
    printf("%02d\n", $number);
}
```

codepad here http://codepad.org/a3Bl4TeA

Answer (score 0):

I have prefer to make my own scalable function to any other length you would like to use.
here for example

```
function format3($number){
   if($number>99){$number=$number;}
     else{ if($number>9){$number="0".$number;} 
      else{$number="00".$number;
         }
     }
  return $number;
}
```

just call format3(/*your value*/) to see your value displaid in three digit
$value=3
echo format3($value) //display 003
You can extend the function for longest patterns formatX()